# How do i Style my ComboBox as well as its items in WPF?

Tags: wpf, combobox, itemtemplate

I have a ComboBox which i want to style with some custom style. I was successful in providing the required style. In the style i have the following elements :

- Template for a toggle button
- A pop-up which holds items of the ComboBox

Almost all the links i referred to, used the same approach. But with this approach i am not able to provide a template for the items in the ComboBox. For some reason the item template i am defining is not being used for rendering the items. Could someone help me out?
I am pasting a sample of code to make my problem statement clear(There might be mistakes in the code, i just want an idea to proceed).

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource MyToggleButton}"/>
                        <Popup >
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Border/>
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Maybe it's because you haven't provided a key to your style that's being referenced in the combobox or something?

Comment: Well, the ComboBox styling is working properly but the items in the pop-up are not being templated properly. So, i don't think there could be any problem with the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to provide a different ControlTemplate for your ComboBoxItem controls you need to set the ItemContainerStyle property on your ComboBox to a Style similar to what you've already done with the parent control, but for ComboBoxItem. ItemTemplate defines a DataTemplate to apply to the data for each item which is then injected into that ComboBoxItem ControlTemplate.

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Border>
                            <ContentPresenter/> <!--ItemTemplate is injected here-->
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomePropertyOnMyDataObject}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: No, i want to provide a completely different look for the ComboBox itself along with the DataTemplate for its items. I could try the solution you have suggested and see if it solves my problem. Anyways, thanks for the quick response.